# Parse date integer in query side in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

The title might be a little tough to understand, so I will explain it first.

Say my data has a column called `date`, which is an `integer` in a `20121013` format.

And I want to output data in year, month, day format.

I am wondering if there is a way in query side to split the data.

Something like this:

```
select date[0:3] as year, date[4:5] as month, date[6:7] as day from blah blah;
```

if this is not possible, I have to create a simple parser that will handle this outside the hive, but I hope there is a way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an integer which is always going to be in `yyyyMMdd` format, you can simply do:

```
select date / 10000 as year, 
       (date % 10000) / 100 as month, 
       date % 1000000 as day 
       from blah blah;
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. thanks a lot hari. I appreciate your help. Best,